# javascript regex [-_.] not first character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I do not want the first letter of these characters `_-.` Used but can use between characters

```
'(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]*$){1,10}'
```

Comment: Please add sample and expected result.

Comment: '(^(?![-_.])[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]*$){1,10}' This problem was solved with me

Answer (score 2):

If `[a-zA-Z0-9-. ]` is the allowed range of characters, should be present 1-10 times and can not start with `-` or `.` then you don't need lookarounds.

You can match the first character `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` and repeat the fully allowed range 0-9 times.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9. -]{0,9}$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1mFbhh/1).

If an underscore is also allowed, you could shorten the pattern using `\w`:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w. -]{0,9}$
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked with some tools online and the follwoing do should do the job fine:

```
const regex = /^[^\_\-\.]{1}(.)*/gm;
const str = `.awdawd`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

I also recommend using the website regex101.com if you wanted to play around with the Javscript regex.